# Why does my external Hard Drive keep squealing?

Tags: external-hard-drive

As soon as I plug in the USB cable to my desktop's USB port, and the external Hard Drive starts spinning, it keeps [scritching](https://soundcloud.com/user-67687430/orange-hd/s-VNxMcBIwTwM?si=952f8e9a43d347bc9f7387e6281099a1).  Please listen to my audio file.

I bought it in 2015, but I plug it in just 4 times a year to backup files. It appears normally  in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Make backups now. Once they start making sounds the end is often near. And yes, you need backups of backups

Comment: Has the acoustic mode of the HDD been modified? See https://superuser.com/questions/18084/enable-aam-on-western-digital-hard-drive  Check the SMART data before following any doom&gloom advice.

Answer (score 0):

HDDs starts to make sounds when the head of the suspension starts rubbing against the main disks. This, as you might guess, leads to data corruption. Therefore, you must copy all the data that is present on the disk to another disk or cloud storage as soon as you can in order to prevent data loss.

Comment: And then destroy the faulty drive.